# Subtitle Above Large Nav Bar Title

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how we could get the subtitle (like a date) above the navbar title when using the prefersLargeTitles feature. Something like the music app. I would also like the large button beside it (like the profile button in the music app). I would still like the large title to animate to the top and become small when the screen is scrolled (like the browse page on the music app).

[image: Music App Subtitle and Large Button Icon]

The code I am using so far is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    collectionView.initialize()
    self.title = "Home Screen"
}
```

Comment: I've not done this before, but have a look at setting the `navigationItem.titleView` rather than just the `title`, and providing a custom `UIView` subclass that contains the two labels.

Comment: If we implement a custom view, the title does not animate up when the view is scrolled. This is probably the way the music app was done though, I guess there isn't another way to do it

Comment: Do you find the solutions? Could you share it?